# get data from dynamic key value in json

Tags: javascript, json, key-value

The requirement is following:
I have to get the location field from page.

```
var input= global.input = document.getElementById("Location");
```

Get the neighborhood area from the json file based on input and show on the page.

I have a json object and have to filter the data from the json object based on the key value (location)

```
var inputLocation=input.value;
```

In my javascript I am getting the error if I use dynamic the key.

I am able to get the json array if I do this `data.Aspen` but i have to get the data from a text field and it can be different so if I call data.inputLocation... its coming undefined

when i use `data.(inputLocation.value)` getting the following error :

> XML filter is applied to non-XML value ({Aspen:[{ID:

```
{
 "Aspen":[
 {
  "ID":"Bellaire",
  "Name":"Bellaire"
 },
 {
  "ID":"Champions Forest",
  "Name":"Champions Forest"
 },
 {
  "ID":"Highland Village",
  "Name":"Highland Village"
 },
 {
  "ID":"Museum District",
  "Name":"Museum District"
 }
 ]
}
```

Comment: I can't understand what your problem is. You may try explaining yourself in a simpler way... give some examples.

Comment: Java isn't Javascript ;)

Comment: @  Luca Matteis Douglas has answered the question..Actually i was unknown to the syntax for getting the value from key.instead of data.(inputLocation.value) ,i used data[inputLocation] and the problem resolved.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can access the property using array-like syntax:

```
data[inputLocation]
```

If `inputLocation` is set to `"Aspen"`, then it is the same as these two lines:

```
data["Aspen"]
data.Aspen
```

Comment: What if we have dynamic locations ? Lets show it might be data[Name][Age], where both name and age can be dynamic. What do we do in that case ?

Comment: Saved me a lot of time in fixing grunt uglify errors due to missing ES6 support. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

get value from dynamic json object Using real time currency converter rest api responce

```
public async Task<JsonResult> ConvertCurrency(float Price, string FromCurrency)
{
    var testcase = FromCurrency + "_USD";
    WebClient web = new WebClient();
    const string ConverterApiURL = "http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q={0}_{1}&compact=ultra&apiKey={{EnterKey}}";
    string url = String.Format(ConverterApiURL, FromCurrency, "USD");

    string response = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);

    var data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
    dynamic result = data.SelectToken(testcase + ".val").ToString();

    var basePrice = float.Parse(result);

    double exchangeRate = Price * basePrice;
    var responce = Math.Round(exchangeRate, 2);
    return Json(responce, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Why have you posted a C# answer on a question asking about JS? Also even in C# what is the need to show how to use a specific API? You could have just said that there is a `SelectToken` method.